# NSMutableDicitionary add new entries my filling out text-fields and clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I've got a single-screen app in which you find two textfields (object and key) and a button (which should store the two Strings in a NSMutableArray. BTW: don't be confused: "merken" is german for "remember" ;)

my Problem is, that I'd like to fill my NSMutableDictionary this way, but right now it can just save the Object and Key the very first time.

This is my according method:

```
-(IBAction)merken:(id)sender { 

    NSString *currentObject = [[NSString alloc] init];NSString *currentKey = [[NSString alloc] init];

    currentObject = [typedObject text];
    currentKey = [typedKey text];

    [dict setValue:currentObject forKey:currentKey];

    //Check if the stings have been added to the Dict.
    int checkLengh = [dict count];
    NSString * checkString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Das Dict hat %d Zeile(n)", checkLengh];
    [checkLabel setText:checkString];

    [typedObject resignFirstResponder];
    [typedKey resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Any Ideas? I've been working on it all day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not in the code you have posted; to figure that out where `dict` is declared and how it is setup etc. needs to be known; but there are some things which might point to what has gone wrong.

First you declare your strings as follows:

```
NSString *currentObject = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

This is **completely** wrong for strings (it is not for all types). An `NSString` is an immutable object and must be given a value when created. However a *variable* of type `NSString *` contains a reference to a string, or `nil` - for when it is referencing nothing. You only need:

```
NSString *currentObject;
```

To declare the variable which will hold the reference to the `NSString` object. If you wish you can go a little further an use:

```
NSString *currentObject = nil;
```

So the variable starts with a known value (otherwise local variables will contain a garbage value, *instance* variables are automatically set to `nil`/`0`/etc. as appropriate). However you will be immediately assigning a value so assigning `nil` is not needed - there is no chance you'll accidentally use a garbage value.

Getting this wrong suggests you might be unclear about how objects and references work, and you may have made mistakes when declaring and allocating your `NSMutableDictionary`.

Second you should use `setObject:forKey:` to set the key/value:

```
[dict setObject:currentObject forKey:currentKey];
```

These two methods are subtly different, you usually want `setObject`; look at the documentation for the differences.

HTH

Comment: To be honest, it took me some time to understand your answer and I think you are 100% right: I might be unclear about objects and references work.

Comment: as a newbie I can't answer to my own question within the next 8 hours. Otherwise I'd like to give you a hint through my declaration...

Comment: @Robbie - you can edit your original question to add additional information; that's not dependent on your status

Comment: Thanks! I'll do better the next time!

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of my situation here is also how I declared the objects:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *typedObject;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *typedKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *checkLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dict;


  - (IBAction)merken:(id)sender;

@end
```

and:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize typedObject;
@synthesize typedKey;
@synthesize checkLabel;
@synthesize dict;
```

Did I mess up the declaration of the NSMutableDictionary?
...in the action I already included your improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate your NSMutableDictionary at some point before you start using it. Keeping a strong reference will not allocate memory automatically.